# Building APK from Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, deployment

Assuming I built Angular 2 app and I want to build an Android app for it too, what would be the most efficent way to do it?

I'm using Angular 2 with the CLI tool to build my app, using ng build --prod to deploy it to web.

I've been googling and found this: https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/ng-chapter-0

I'm looking for the best way to do it to save time, those are my options (feel free to let me know about any other..):

1. Build android native app using Android studio. Then I need to update both android files and angular 2 files seperately (the API stays the same, the API is equally for both)
2. using Nativescript as linked above
3. any other way or suggestion by you to make my angular2 app available for android/ios?

Answer (score 1):

You ought to use [Ionic Framework](https://ionicframework.com/getting-started) intended for compiling `APK` from `Angular2` sources.

There is another more low-level tool: [Apache Cordova Project](https://cordova.apache.org/)

Answer (score 0):

The Requirements
There are only a few requirements to make this project successful.

Node.js 4+

NativeScript 2.1+

Angular CLI

The Android SDK, Xcode, or both

Node.js ships with a very important tool called the Node Package Manager (NPM).  With it we can get all dependencies for both the Angular 2 web application and NativeScript mobile application.

Angular 2 support didn’t become available in NativeScript until version 2.0.  Finally, to build for Android or iOS you need the various platform SDKs.